# How to Get Value From Excel By Sheet ?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-5

Below is my code here everything is ok but one thing that creating problem is that the attribute which i am inserting in database from excel sheet is not getting the exact value.loop is also getting the value from other sheet if they contain the same attribute name.

Here is my Code

```
 string sqlConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + outputFile + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;Persist Security Info=False";
                    //Create Connection to Excel work book and add oledb namespace
                    OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(sqlConnectionString);
                    excelConnection.Open();
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                    dt = excelConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                    if (dt == null)
                    {
                        return null;
                    }

                    String[] excelSheets = new String[dt.Rows.Count];
                    int t = 0;
                    //excel data saves in temp file here.
                    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        excelSheets[t] = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                        t++;
                    }
                    OleDbConnection excelConnection1 = new OleDbConnection(sqlConnectionString);
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    for (int i = 0; i <= excelSheets.Length - 1; i++)
                    {
                        string query = string.Format("Select * from [{0}]", excelSheets[i]);
                        using (OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, excelConnection1))
                        {
                            dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
                        }

                       //Debug.Write("UserinfoId==" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["UserInfoID"].ToString());
                        for (int j = 0; j < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; j++)
                        {
                            SqlConnection sqlc = new SqlConnection();
                            sqlc.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
                            if (excelSheets[i] == "IdentityUser$")
                            {
                                //Debug.Write("Id==" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[j]["Id"].ToString() + "\n");

                            }
                            else if (excelSheets[i] == "USERINFO$")
                            {                              

                                //Debug.Write("UserinfoId==" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[j]["UserInfoID"].ToString()+"\n");
                            }
```

Now when i am inserting userinfoId from Excel Sheet USERINFO$ it is searching from IdentityUser$ table too because of that i am getting the UserinfoId from that Sheet too

Comment: Try to move the DataSet ds = new DataSet() inside the loop over sheets. I think that if you call Fill 2 times on a datasheet, the values are merged, so you will get values from sheet 1 with values from sheet 2. That is why, where on sheet 2 you don't have values, you get the values from sheet 1

Answer (score 0):

This Solve my Problem. i have put   `DataSet ds = new DataSet();`inside the for loop and it works.

```
    string sqlConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + outputFile + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;Persist Security Info=False";
                        //Create Connection to Excel work book and add oledb namespace
                        OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(sqlConnectionString);
                        excelConnection.Open();
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                        dt = excelConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                        if (dt == null)
                        {
                            return null;
                        }

                        String[] excelSheets = new String[dt.Rows.Count];
                        int t = 0;
                        //excel data saves in temp file here.
                        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                        {
                            excelSheets[t] = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                            t++;
                        }
                        OleDbConnection excelConnection1 = new OleDbConnection(sqlConnectionString);                   
                        for (int i = 0; i <= excelSheets.Length - 1; i++)
                        {
                            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                            string query = string.Format("Select * from [{0}]", excelSheets[i]);
                            using (OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, excelConnection1))
                            {
                                dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
                            }


                                    for (int j = 0; j < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; j++)
                                    {
                                        SqlConnection sqlc = new SqlConnection();
                                        sqlc.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
                                        if (excelSheets[i] == "IdentityUser$")
                                        {                                   

                                        }
                                        else if (excelSheets[i] == "USERINFO$")
                                        { 
                                        }
                                      }
                                  }
```